# How to upload a file to Cloudinary from page.server?

Tags: node.js, sveltekit, cloudinary

I Want to upload a file to Cloudinary with their nodejs SDK. I'm using Sveltekit and need to understand the way how it needs to be done. The flow:

Frontend: page.svelte Uploading a file with a `<form>`, submitting and calling server action `?/upload`

```html
<form
    method="post"
    enctype="multipart/form-data"
    use:enhance
    action="?/upload"

    <input
        class="hidden"
        name="image"
        id="file-to-upload"
        type="file"
        accept=".png,.jpg"
    />

    <button class="border bg-orange-400 rounded py-2 text-sm"
        >Upload!</button
    >
</form>
```

Backend: +page.server.ts

```js
import { v2 as cloudinary, type UploadApiResponse } from 'cloudinary'
import type { Actions } from './$types';

export const actions = {
    upload: async ({request}) => {

        const data = request.formData();
        const file = (await data).get('image') as File


        if (file){

            const buffer = await file.arrayBuffer();
            const stream = await file.stream();

            const upload_stream = cloudinary.uploader.upload_stream((error, image) => {
                ?????
            });

        } else {
            console.error('no file to upload')
        }
    }
} satisfies Actions;
```

Reads FormData and trying to upload submitted file to Cloudinary. But how to do this? Cloudinary has some methods like upload_stream but i cant figure out the way.

I've tried common cloudinary.uploader.upload function, but it wants a string as an input.
And i have only buffer and stream from FormData. I don't want to create base64 from file contents or upload a file to Cloudinary directly from browser.

Seems like I need to convert recieved FormData's file to another format, which can be successfully uploaded to cloudinary's **upload_stream()** function, for example. I really need help to make understanding how to correctly pass it from SvelteKit's backend to Cloudinary in the right way.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

So i found a solution. The trick is to convert file's `ArrayBuffer` to node's `Buffer`, so then Cloudinary's `upload_stream` works like a charm. Because of callback-nature of this function, i wrapped it in `Promise`.

```
async upload(file: File) {
    const arrayBuffer = await file.arrayBuffer();
    const buffer = Buffer.from(arrayBuffer) //  <-- convert to Buffer

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        cloudinary.uploader.upload_stream({ resource_type: "image" }, onDone).end(buffer)

        function onDone(error, result) {
            if (error) {
                return reject({ success: false, error });
            }
            return resolve({ success: true, result })
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `File` also has a `.stream()` method; it might be possible to pipe that directly without first reading the entire file into a buffer.

Comment: You definitely right, File.stream() exists. But i've tried and not succeeded with this approach :)

Answer (score 1):

After considerable effort, the following process now works smoothly, effectively managing results and inputs for SvelteKit. Essentially, an image is obtained from the SvelteKit frontend, sent to the SvelteKit backend, then forwarded to Cloudinary. Finally, the public URL is returned to the frontend.

+page.svelte

```
<script>
    import {Label} from "$lib/components/ui/label"
    import {Input} from "$lib/components/ui/input"
    import {Button} from "$lib/components/ui/button"
    import {applyAction, enhance} from '$app/forms'

    let public_image_url = ""
    const handleResults = () => {
        return async ({result}) => {
            console.log("result: ", result)
            if (result.data.success) {
                public_image_url = result.data.public_image_url
            } else {
                console.log("error: ", result)
            }

            await applyAction(result)
        }
    }
</script>

<div class="space-y-2">
    <h2 class="text-2xl font-bold">Upload file to Cloudinary</h2>
</div>

<form method="POST" action="?/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" use:enhance={handleResults}>

    <div class="space-y-2 mt-2">
        <Label for="fileName">File Name</Label>
        <Input type="text" id="fileName" name="fileName"/>
    </div>

    <div class="space-y-2 mt-2">
        <Input type="file" id="image" name="image"/>
    </div>
    <Button class="w-full space-y-2 mt-2" type="submit">
        Upload
    </Button>

</form>

{#if public_image_url !== ""}
    <p>Image</p>
    <img src={public_image_url}>
{/if}
```

+page.server.js

```
    import {v2 as cloudinary} from 'cloudinary'

    cloudinary.config({
        cloud_name: '',
        api_key: '',
        api_secret: '',
        secure: true
    });

    export const actions = {
        upload: async (event) => {
            try {
                const formData = await event.request.formData();
                const file = await formData.get('image');
                const fileName = await formData.get('fileName');
                const arrayBuffer = await file.arrayBuffer();
                const buffer = Buffer.from(arrayBuffer);

                // Create a Promise to handle the upload process
                const uploadPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    cloudinary.uploader.upload_stream((error, result) => {
                        if (error) {
                            console.error(error);
                            reject(error);
                        } else {
                            console.log(result.url);
                            resolve(result.url); // Resolve with the public URL
                        }
                    }).end(buffer);
                });

                // Wait for the upload to complete and get the public URL
                const publicUrl = await uploadPromise;

                return { success: true, public_image_url: publicUrl };
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
                return { success: false, error: 'Error uploading image' };
            }
        }
    };
```